# Elasticsearch analyzer to remove quoted sentences

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-analyzers

I'm trying to create an analyzer that would remove (or replace by white/empty space) a quoted sentence within a document.

Such as: `this is my \"test document\"`

I'd like, for example, the term vector to be: `[this, is, my]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daniel Answer is correct, but as corresponding regex and replacement are missing, I am providing it, which includes the test of your text.

Index setting as below which uses pattern replace char.

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "char_filter": [
                        "my_char_filter"
                    ],
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "char_filter": {
                "my_char_filter": {
                    "type": "pattern_replace",
                    "pattern": "\"(.*?)\"",
                    "replacement": ""
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After that using [analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) it generates below tokens:

POST _analyze

```
{
    "text": "this is my \"test document\"",
    "analyzer" : "my_analyzer"
}
```

Output of above API:

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "this",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 4,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "is",
            "start_offset": 5,
            "end_offset": 7,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "my",
            "start_offset": 8,
            "end_offset": 10,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could configure your own analyzer with a [Pattern Replace Character Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html) for this field with that replaces everything in between the escaped double quotes with nothing.